# how to join muliple tables at a time using linq to sql?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

**Users:**

```
userid    name     email
  1       venkat   v@g.com
  2       venu     ve@g.com
  3       raghu    r@g.com
```

**Partners:**

```
    id   userid   partnerid  status
    1     1        2           1
    2     1        3           1
```

**location:**

```
    id   userid    lat    lon
    1     1        12.00  13.00
    2     2        14.00  12.00
    3     3        14.00  14.23
```

Query:

```
var result = from partner in Partners
                join user in Users on partner.UserId equals user.PartnerId
                join location in Locations on patner.UserId equals location.PartnerId
                where partner.UserId == 1
                select new { PartnerId = partner.PartnerId, PartnerName = user.Name, Lat = location.Lat, Lon = location.Lon };
```

by passing `userid=1` as parameter I am getting this result:

```
partnerid  patnername      lat            lon
  2         venkat         14.00         12.00
  3         venkat         14.00         14.23
```

by observation of above result here partnernames are wrong for `partnerid = 2` - `patname` was  `venu` but displaying "venkat"

For `partnerid = 3`, partnername was `raghu` but displaying `venkat`.

How to display the correct partner names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this JOIN here is wrong:

```
var result = from partner in Partners
             join user in Users on user.UserId equals partner.PartnerId
```

You're joining a user on his `userId` to a partner using his `PartnerID`.

Don't you need to join a user to a partner using `PartnerID` in both cases? Something like this:

```
var result = from partner in Partners
             join user in Users on user.PartnerId equals partner.PartnerId
```